# notational conventions for statistics (like hypothesis test statistics)

Tags: statistics

I am wondering about something. I know I should write function non-italic. like `sin` and `cos`, But I am not sure if test statistic symbols like $T^2$ should be written italic (default) or with `\mathrm`.

for example: `$T^2$-Hotelling's` is correct or `$\mathrm{T}^2$-Hotellings`?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Speaking purely for myself (I'm an econometrician...), I would choose the first version, i.e., `$T^2$`. However, what matters most is notational consistency: Use either `$T^2$` or `$\mathrm{T}^2$` consistently, and your readers won't get confused.

Comment: Thanks @Mico. I Saw in articles that using the first version, But because test statistics are a type functions it made me confused. Anyway I think you right. consistency is matters.

Comment: I agree with @Mico. This is e.g. what the APA requires.

Comment: Do `\newcommand{\Tsq}{T^2}` in your preamble and use `$\Tsq$-Hotellings`. This way you can change the output by simply modifying the definition.

Comment: This is really off-topic because it is not about a TeX issue. If the question was, 'I need `T` to be upright, but it comes out italic - how can I correct this?' then it would be on-topic. But 'should it be upright or italic?' is off-topic. How to implement things is on-topic. Whether they should be implemented is generally not.

Comment: @cfr Thanks. I didn't know where should I ask this unfortunately. I think this question is off-topic stats.stackexchange.com too.

Comment: @SirSaleh Hmm ... that would have been my best guess as to where to ask.